# How to optimize laravel code to speed up TTFB?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i am trying to optimize the below code to speed up the ttfb time that is actually 11 second (tooo high).
The json contain thousands of geo coordinates used to print polylines on Google Maps.
There is something wrong on the code or i need to increase server resources?
Thanks

```
public function getTrackingData($scheduleId)
{
$segmenti = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT a.segmentid,b.colore FROM schedules_trackings a left join devices b on a.device_id=b.id where schedule_id = :scheduleId  group by a.segmentid,b.colore,b.sigla"), array(
  'scheduleId' => $scheduleId,
));
$resultArray = json_decode(json_encode($segmenti), true);

$tracking = array();
foreach ($resultArray as $seg) {
  $geodata = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT a.latitude, a.longitude FROM schedules_trackings a left join devices b on a.device_id=b.id where schedule_id = :scheduleId and segmentId = :segmentId  order by a.created_at"), array(
    'scheduleId' => $scheduleId,
    'segmentId' => $seg['segmentid']
  ));

  $tracking[] = array(
    'segment' => $seg['segmentid'],
    'color' => $seg['colore'],
    'geodata' => $geodata
  );
}
return response()->json($tracking, 200);
}
```

Comment: Why the second query in a loop? It looks like you can select `a.latitude, a.longitude` in the original query.

Comment: i need to divide list of coordinate by segment, on first query get the list of segment in second list of coordinates by segment.